# How to get controller method parameters in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have implemented a controller to give access of data of candidates.

```
class List_Controller extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
         $data[]=array();

         /*
         Here I want to get value of $area parameter, to save into logs
        */
         $userId=$this->session->userdata('userId'); 
         // save logs 
         $this->UrlAccessHistory->save($this->router->class,$this->router->method,$userId,"Web Application");

     }

    public function fetchList($area=null){
        // fetch list of records from specified area 
    }
}
```

`$this->router->className` gives name of controller Class and `$this->router->method` gives name of of function called.

Please help to get the list of parameters at location (see comments in code) in the constructor, so that I can store it in the logs.

Comment: how u r passing your `$area` in your method

Comment: I am passing uri components: "http://localhost/tagoreitutor-web-app/index.php/stdc/listTopics/1/11/40" stdc is controller, listTopics is method then parameters to method/function

Comment: Have you tried `$this->uri->uri_string()`? - https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::uri_string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [URI Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html):

```
$this->uri->segment(n);
```

Comment: this must be a comment no answer.

Comment: It qualifies as an answer to the requirements of the OP, I guess.

Comment: Ok.Hope to be useful

Comment: $this->uri->component(n) gives an element of URI from nth index. I want to get list of parameters passed to controller method. "http://localhost/tagoreitutor-web-app/index.php/stdc/listTopics/1/11/40". In this URL 1, 11 and 40 are parameters to controller method.

Comment: Have you tried `$this->uri->uri_string()`? - https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::uri_string

Comment: we got list of parameters by exploding uri_string() `explode("/",$this->uri->uri_string())`

Answer (score 0):

I have added a function inside controller to get list of controller parameters

```
function getControllerParametersFromUri($uri_string){
    $list = explode("/",$uri_string);
    // skip controller and method names from 
    // return array list 
    return array_slice($list,2);
}

// call function by passing uri_string to get parameters list
print_r($this->getControllerParametersFromUri($this->uri->uri_string()));
```

@Sujit Agarwal  $this->uri->segment(3) also works,

but if we need list of all parameters then we may explode uri_string